# What is the best approach for building a Quran reading app?

Tags: react-native

I'm building a Quran reading option in an React-native app. I have some troubles finding the right approche concerning using pdf or png images.
I have tried `react-native-pdf` but i have some issues. The png option gives the best rendering result in 'PORTRAIT' but in 'LANDSCAPE' the image cant be scrolled vertically to see the entire image; ive tried `scrollView` inside  `FlatList`.

Thanks!

Comment: Consider using text files.

Comment: Are you solve it ?

Comment: Yes, see my other question about it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56669733/scrollview-content-image-is-cropped-when-phone-is-in-landscape-mode

Comment: Hey @B.Mohammad, which API used to get Quran Data?

Comment: Hi, for now we dont use any API, our solution was using jpeg images in `FlatList`  with horizontal enabled. But this approche is not the best as the FlatList can get laggy, also the size of the images is like 70 Mo. I can suggest to look up for the epub format, we will go for it inchaAllah for v2.

Comment: Hello, I am also building a Quran reading app,  I am unable to display ayah in the same line there is a random line break. can you recommend how I can display ayah in the same line as it is in the Quran?

Comment: I would recommend using a epub file of the Quran, this way it will look good on the app

Comment: @B.Mohammad Can I view ePub files in react native?

Comment: @AnasIkhlas check this lib:https://github.com/victorsoares96/epubjs-react-native it had some issues when I tried it a while a ago, but now it looks like its maintained the last commit is on august.

Comment: you're welcome Allahoma yassir

Answer (score 2):

Avoid PDF.

Check this repository:
https://github.com/semarketir/quranjson
It contains everything you need to build a quran app in react and host everything in your own server or offline

Use this if you want more control:
https://alquran.cloud/api
But it will require the user to be online